# size of array in dynamic allocation problem

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

I have to solve this problem: "Write a program that reads from the keyboard a sequence of 10 integers, and writes the same sequence in reverse order, dividing by 2 the even elements of the sequence."

I want to know the size of the array p to print it in the reverse order but when I try to get the size of array with "l = sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])" the for loop below doesn't works.

```
int main(){
    int n,i;
    int *p;
    int l;

    printf("How long the array? ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    p = malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    if(p != NULL){
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            printf("Insert number in index (%d) of array: ",i);
            scanf("%d",p+i);
        }

        l = sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0]);

        for (i=n;i == 0;i--){
            if(p[i] % 2 == 0){
                printf("%d ",p[i]/2);
            }
            else{
                printf("%d",p[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        printf("ERROR!!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You already have the length above; it's `n`.

Comment: Oh right!! what an idiot i am.. anyway can you say me why i can't have the size of p in this way? what i'd write to have it?

Comment: In general you can't tell from a pointer what the size of the array it points to is. The usual convention is to pass the size along with the pointer, if it isn't obvious.

Comment: Ah right, because obviously when i use dynamic allocation i'll say the size of the array right? Sorry but i'm new to this

Comment: Right -- whoever did the dynamic allocation knows what the size they requested was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of sizeof will be a size in bytes - not of the array, but the pointer, which is an integer in this case. What you want is the length. You have the length stored in n.

Your for-loop is a bit confusing. Try using n - 1 (the length of the array) in order to start the loop by accessing the last index value of the array. Also, the `printf` inside the else block doesn't space the output correctly.  Try the following code:

```
for (i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
{
    if (p[i] % 2 == 0)
    {
        printf("%d ", p[i] / 2);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d ", p[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> when I try to get the size of array with `l = sizeof(p)/sizeof(p[0])` the for loop below doesn't works.

This fails as `p` is a pointer, not an array.  The size of `p` is something like  4 or 8.

> I want to know the size of the array p

`p` is not an array.  Simply use the `n` as used in the allocation.